# Why does Neo hit Ctrl+X?

Tags: the-matrix

When Trinity hacks into his computer and delivers her message, Neo hits <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. Why?

On Windows hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> will cut (I'm not sure about other operating systems).

A little searching around lead to a forum that suggested a few possibilities:

- It was a way to exit DOS applications
- The OS Neo uses was custom made by him or MetaCortex, so <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> might have a different meaning.

Is their any official explanation?

Comment: The operating system he's using isn't Windows; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjoad6gcRzs Which means that the keystrokes would be relevant for that OS

Comment: Notably, the keystrokes are mentioned in the [1998 draft script](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/the_matrix.pdf) so it's not just the Second Unit Director pressing random buttons; *Neo's eye pries open. He sits up, one eye still closed, looking around, unsure of where he is. He notices the
screen. He types "CTRL X" but the letter "T" appears.*

Comment: In many command prompts, ctrl + z ends the current process. I can never remember that and end up hitting ctrl +c or ctrl + x first. Maybe Neo fat fingered the command.

Comment: @Sethen - More likely it's (CTRL + eXit) for Hollywood viewers

Comment: A lot of Emacs command sequences start with CTRL-x, like C-x C-c to exit, or C-x C-s to save.

Comment: I’m guessing it’s a Hollywood OS command.

Comment: The watching someone type on terminal reminded me of unix (talk) https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk_(software), but ctrl-x doesn't do anything in that. Maybe one of the follow on versions like ytalk. But the fact that Neos next action is to hit escape repeatedly leads me to believe he's trying to kill the program

Comment: The Matrix universe is different from ours, so you can't expect everything to work the same.

Comment: @Valorum I’m pretty sure every one of the big os's has ctrl/command + x. Windows, Mac, and I believe Linux.

Comment: My guess is that it's movie logic. X is the cool letter. *Cut* command aside, you could abstractly picture ctrl-x doing some cool ambiguous-yet-categorical thing in some application Neo is using. Imagine if he pressed some other letter, say ctrl-h. Everyone would wonder about it for the rest of the movie.

Comment: I always assumed it was an out-of-universe accessibility thing. Viewers who know linux understand what ctrl+c does, but those who don't, don't. But if he pushes ctrl+x, it's not hard in context to rationalize that it stands for e**X**it.

Comment: Pedantic but somewhat relevant point: *Windows* doesn't do anything in response to Ctrl-X. It is a common convention in Windows *applications* to map Ctrl-X to "Cut", but it's perfectly possible for a Windows application to do whatever it likes with it - including "exit".

Answer (score 12):

ctrl+x is how you exit the terminal based text editor popular on Linux systems called "nano".

Neo was trying to exit what was happening, in the same fashion.

Comment: https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/cheatsheet.html

Comment: The Matrix released March 1999. Nano released (as TIP) November 1999. Was there a predecessor to Nano that used the same keys to exit?

Comment: nano is a GPL-compatible clone of pico, which is from 1989.

Comment: (To resolve the ambiguity: it's the text editor which is called ‘nano’, not the Linux systems :-)

Answer (score 4):

Several of the common shells used in Unix (and by inheritance, Linux) use or can be configured to use ctl-x as an abbreviated exit command.  Unix was found on some microcomputer systems (including the Tandy Model 12 that dated from the mid-1980s -- I used one on a dial-up connection for a while).

This command, then, could be symbolic; Neo issuing an "exit" command is equivalent to wanting to "exit" the shell that is the Matrix.